# Quoting in sed for file comparison

Tags: sed, comparison, quoting

i would like to ask a question in regards to sed, it has been asked before but i frankly cannot understand where the error is, (it propably has something to do with quoting).

Most posts i ve seen mention that if i want to call the value of a variable into sed i need to avoid single quotes because then it takes the $var literally, finds no value and outputs error "no previous regular expression".

I ve created another version of this file comparison by using cat | grep and that works, i was just wondering if it was possible with sed, to print only the matching lines in each iteration of the while.

Still, that's the same error i get with the double quotes, could someone help me?

```
while IFS='' read line1 || [[ -n $line1 ]]; do
echo $line1
sed -n "/$line1/p" $fileA > $outputfile
done < $fileB
```

Comment: It prints the correct lines, it just gives me this error : sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Comment: What line value(s) cause that error from `sed`?

Comment: I have no idea, how can i find that out? I tried bash +x scriptname but it didnt really take me through the step by step, is there a possibility that a blank line is fed into sed? that's why the error?

Comment: `bash -x scriptname` or `set -x` in the script but you already have `echo $line1` in the script so which line is output right before the `sed` error?

Comment: you are correct, the filter file had a blank line, sed was reading it as :    `+ sed -n /10111213141517/p comparebase.txt
+ IFS=
+ read line1
+ sed -n //p comparebase.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

Comment: I think the error was because sed did not find a regexp to hit...i m not sure

Comment: Yes. A pattern of `//` to sed means "use the previous regular expression" and that's not possible for the first pattern in a sed script.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: why no using a `grep -f `instead of this sed (part of a biggest sed action list ?)?

Comment: You re right, and it proved to be quicker too. I eventually ended up with a solution using `cat | grep` to output the same lines